# How upgrade lock helps avoid deadlock in reader/writer lock

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I understand that upgrade lock tries to solve classic deadlock example where two concurrent threads holding onto Read lock and trying to acquire writelock will deadlock.

> Thread A: S lock (acquired)
>
> Thread B: S lock (acquired)
>
> Thread A: X lock (waiting for B to release S lock)
>
> Thread B: X lock (waiting for A to release S lock) DEADLOCKED

Why same problem is not with upgrade lock? [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation says that only one thread may be granted upgrade lock and it is permitted to do so while other threads are still  holding onto S lock. Can someone explain why two concurrent threads running this pattern will not run into deadlock?

```
  lock.AcquireSharedLock()      // Thread A and B both acquired this S lock

  lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();  // Only one (e.g. A) acquired U lock and other (e.g. B) is blocked here.

  if(somecondition)
  {
    lock.AcquireExclusiveLock();   // A tries to acquire X lock. But wouldn't it get blocked since B is already holding onto S lock? B is already blocked, so this has to be a deadlock
  }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny that I have just answered the same question for SQL Server and `UPDATE` statements: [How do UPDATE locks prevent a common form of deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353327/how-do-update-locks-prevent-a-common-form-of-deadlock/22354079#22354079)

The key aspect to the answer is that upgradable transactions *never take an S-lock*. They immediately U-lock. Therefore, there is never a conflict between an S-lock and an X-lock.

In your example,

```
lock.AcquireSharedLock()
```

should never exist. You *either* S-lock *or* U-lock. Not in sequence, but either of them.

Comment: I understand U-lock is acquired from beginning of the transaction. Say Transaction A holds a U-lock, and Transaction B holds a S-lock. Later they do the writes. But when A starts to acquire X-lock while B also wants to acquire X-lock, wouldn't that still deadlock?