# How do UPDATE locks prevent a common form of deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The [SQL Server books online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) say that `UPDATE` locks prevent a common form of deadlock:

> ## Update Locks
>
> Update (U) locks prevent a common form of deadlock.

How do they prevent a common form of deadlock?

### What do i mean by that?

A common form of deadlock is when two processes attempt to escalate from a Shared (S) lock (i.e. *read lock*) to a Exclusive (X) lock:

```
Process A                       Process B
========================        ========================
Acquire Shared lock
                                Acquire Shared lock
Attempt to escalate to X
Escalation waits on B 
                                Attempt to escalate to X
                                Escalation waits on A
```

***Deadlock***. Both processes are waiting on each other.

This is all explained in the BOL:

> A typical update pattern consists of a transaction reading a record, acquiring a shared (S) lock on the resource (page or row), and then modifying the row, which requires lock conversion to an exclusive (X) lock. If two transactions acquire shared-mode locks on a resource and then attempt to update data concurrently, one transaction attempts the lock conversion to an exclusive (X) lock. The shared-mode-to-exclusive lock conversion must wait because the exclusive lock for one transaction is not compatible with the shared-mode lock of the other transaction; a lock wait occurs. The second transaction attempts to acquire an exclusive (X) lock for its update. Because both transactions are converting to exclusive (X) locks, and they are each waiting for the other transaction to release its shared-mode lock, a deadlock occurs.

### Use an update lock to prevent the deadlock

The Books Online doesn't explain how the update (U) lock prevents this common form of deadlock, all they do say is:

> To avoid this potential deadlock problem, update (U) locks are used. Only one transaction can obtain an update (U) lock to a resource at a time. If a transaction modifies a resource, the update (U) lock is converted to an exclusive (X) lock. Otherwise, the lock is converted to a shared-mode lock.

The description is incomplete. If you look at the phrase *"only one transaction can obtain an update (U) lock to a resource at a time"*. That is no different from an exclusive (X) lock - only one transaction can obtain an exclusive (X) lock to a resource at at time. But lets try to figure it out anyway:

First what we assume is a normal update process:

- Acquire shared (S) lock
- Attempt to escalate to update (U) lock
- Perform update
- Altering of value is required, escalate to exclusive (X) lock
- Escalate to exclusive (X) lock
- perform update
- release all locks

So now add a second process

```
Process A                       Process B
========================        ========================
Acquire Shared lock
                                Acquire Shared lock
Attempt to escalate to U
Escalation waits on B 
                                Attempt to escalate to U
                                Escalation waits on A
```

***Deadlock***. Both processes are waiting on each other.

How does an update (U) lock prevent a common form of deadlock?

Comment: this offers a good explanation http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/10/10/update-with-updlock/

Answer (score 7):

> The description is incomplete. If you look at the phrase "only one
>   transaction can obtain an update (U) lock to a resource at a time".
>   That is no different from an exclusive (X) lock - only one transaction
>   can obtain an exclusive (X) lock to a resource at at time.

U-locks are compatible with S-locks which is not the case for X-locks. This means that while the rows to be written to are determined (using U-locks), other readers are still allowed.

> So now add a second process...

The misunderstanding here is, that writers upgrade from S to U. This is not the case. They use U from the start. They upgrade from U to X later, but that has no meaning regarding deadlocks in this case.

To make this more clear: Let's assume we run the following statement:

```
UPDATE T SET SomeCol = 1 WHERE (ID BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AND (SomeOtherCond = 1)
```

Assume, that this is executed using a range scan on the clustered index on `ID`, and that `SomeOtherCond = 1` is only true for the row `ID = 2`. This will get you U-locks for both rows, and an upgrade to X for the row with `ID = 2`. The U-lock for row `ID = 2` will be released early.

Comment: "They use U from the start". I think I understand, but just to clarify: Does this mean that when the query planner sees that a transaction both selects and then updates a row, then in that case it would take U lock from the start for that row. So another similar query won't get a lock until the first transaction completes.

Comment: This also means that, an alternative way to prevent a deadlock would be: When the query planner sees a transaction that both selects and updates a row, it takes a X lock from the start. This should also prevent the deadlock, but it would limit concurrency. The way U lock help with concurrency is that if the first query takes a U lock from the start, and there is a second query that does only reads, and then the second query is still able to acquire S lock for reads. Does this sound right?

Comment: @Turbo First, the query planner looks at individual statements only. The U lock strategy is used for the table reference that receives the update. So in `UPDATE e1 FROM Employees e1 JOIN Employees e2 on ...`) only the `e1` access gets U locked. Yes, taking an X lock would also avoid the deadlock. Yes, U locks help with concurrency.

Comment: I understand U-lock is acquired from beginning of the transaction. Say Transaction A holds a U-lock, and Transaction B holds a S-lock. Later they do the writes. But when A starts to acquire X-lock while B also wants to acquire X-lock, wouldn't that still deadlock?

Answer (score 2):

An update lock is used to find rows that are to be updated, so are used by DELETE and UPDATE statements. Once rows are found for Update then the lock is converted to an X lock.

See [Kalen Delany Blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2009/11/13/update-locks.aspx)